# Baum nested set, how to get category in random order?

Tags: php, laravel-5, nested-sets

I'm using  [Baum nested set](https://github.com/etrepat/baum)  for category and sub-category in my application with Laravel 5.2 (The categories I use them as my menu), I want the menu to keep changing on page refresh and when user navigate to different pages.

Just wondering if there's a way I can fetch category using [Baum Nested set](https://github.com/etrepat/baum) in random order.

currently using:

```
Category::all()->toHierarchy()->get();
```

It works fine, but when I try

```
Category::inRandomOrder()->toHierarchy()->get();
```

doesn't work.

Anyone tried this before?

Comment: `Category::all()->toHierarchy()->get()->shuffle();` Perhaps?

Comment: hmmm, that sound better, but then `shuffle()` will always shuffle around same set of result, just change of order. I want some new set of result at every page refresh

Comment: Oh right; apologies, that wasn't clear. What does your `inRandomOrder` scope do exactly? When you say it doesn't work, what exactly happens?

Comment: Method inRandomOrder does not exist, when I do this: `Category::all()->toHierarchy()->inRandomOrder()->get()`

Comment: Have a look at [local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#local-scopes) which will allow you to create that method. Give it a go and then edit your question with what you've tried if you have further problems